# Question about command line arguments in Fortran

Tags: fortran, command-line-arguments

I have a question regarding the command-line arguments. I know what they are but I was wondering if they can be used for example on a subroutine or a function. For example, in my program I pass 2 values by command-line so when I run it I type for example

```
./main 5,20
```

Is it possible to create a subroutine that reads values from the command-line? Or I have to add them to my main and then pass them to my functions,subroutines etc?

Answer (score 0):

**What is possible in Fortran**

> Is it possible to create a subroutine that reads values from the command-line?

In any program/function/subroutine you can call the following procedures: `command_argument_count` ([gfortran-doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/COMMAND_005fARGUMENT_005fCOUNT.html#COMMAND_005fARGUMENT_005fCOUNT)) and `get_command_argument` ([gfortran-doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT.html#GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT)).

Those will help to get commandline arguments but you will still have to type cast them to their correct data type though.

> Or I have to add them to my main and then pass them to my functions,subroutines etc?

You can get them anywhere in your code.

---

**Best practice**

Even though one can get/parse commandline arguments anywhere in code it is best to do that in a separate part of your main program.
That part should do the following

1. get the commandline arguments
2. parse them to the correct data type
3. save them in internal variables

Once you have them saved in internal variables you can hand them as arguments to other procedures.

This way it is easier to handle/debug large code bases.

---

Note that you need to separate arguments by a space rather than by comma, e.g.

```
./main 5 20
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for the input. But if I have them in a different file and not the main one, how can I input the values? What i mean is for example I have a file main.f90 and another one with functions let s call it functions.f90 . I run my program by ./main 5 20 . And now let s say I have a subroutine in my functions.f90 which requires 2 additional inputs do I run it like for example ./main 5 20 10 15 ?where the first 2 values go to my main and all 4 go to my subroutine?

Comment: @Alex I'd encourage you to add that example to your question. I will provide an answer as an edit to my original answer.

Comment: @Alex I hope that the "Best practice" section answers your comment's question

Answer (score 0):

Passing arguments from a CLI to a program function is shown below. The usefulness of using a CLI for numbers depends on how complex / how many options is your program going to have to handle:

- If they are many / too complex, then, I would rather use an input file instead of a simple CLI.
- If instead a simple CLI is good enough for what you need, you could write a simple wrapper that pre-processes the CLI information into well-defined Fortran data structures, which you can then pass to your program anywhere you like.

In the following example, I've cooked a simple CLI that:

- assumes that all CLI inputs are numbers
- `integer` or `real` numbers on input are sent to two separate arrays (just to show how you can change functionality *at input only*)
- both separately processed by the program function

```
module simple_cli
  implicit none
  private
  
  type, public :: cli_options
     integer, allocatable :: a(:)
     real   , allocatable :: b(:)
     
     contains 
     
       procedure :: destroy => cli_destroy
       procedure :: parse => cli_parse
       procedure :: nA => cli_nA
       procedure :: nB => cli_nB
  
  end type cli_options
  
  contains
  
 
  ! Clean memory
  elemental subroutine cli_destroy(this)
     class(cli_options), intent(inout) :: this
     if (allocated(this%a))deallocate(this%a)
     if (allocated(this%b))deallocate(this%b)
  end subroutine cli_destroy    
  
  ! # of "A" items
  elemental integer function cli_nA(this) 
    class(cli_options), intent(in) :: this
    cli_nA = merge(size(this%a),0,allocated(this%a))
  end function cli_nA

  ! # of "B" items
  elemental integer function cli_nB(this) 
    class(cli_options), intent(in) :: this
    cli_nB = merge(size(this%b),0,allocated(this%b))
  end function cli_nB
  
  ! Parse command line arguments
  subroutine cli_parse(this)
     class(cli_options), intent(out) :: this
     
     integer :: iArg,nInputArg,nReal,nInteger,strlen,int_value,int_OK,real_OK
     real :: real_value
     character(1024) :: string
     
     call this%destroy()
     
     ! Number of input arguments
     nInputArg = command_argument_count(); if (nInputArg<=0) return
     
     ! Parse each input arguments
     nReal = 0
     nInteger = 0
     
     do iArg=1,nInputArg
        
        ! Get i-th command line argument
        call get_command_argument(iArg,value=string,length=strlen)
        
        ! Read as both integer and real
        read(string(1:strlen),*,iostat=int_OK ) int_value
        read(string(1:strlen),*,iostat=real_OK) real_value
        
        if (int_OK==0) then 
           call int_add(this%a,int_value)
        elseif (real_OK==0) then 
           call real_add(this%b,real_value)
        else
           print *, ' catastrophic CLI error: cannot interpret command <'//string(1:strlen)//'>.'
           stop    
        endif          
         
     end do
     
  end subroutine cli_parse

  ! Helper function to fill an array (slow!)
  pure subroutine real_add(array,value)
     real, allocatable, intent(inout) :: array(:)
     real, intent(in) :: value
     real, allocatable :: tmp(:)
     integer :: n
     n = merge(size(array),0,allocated(array))
     allocate(tmp(n+1))
     if (n>0) tmp(1:n) = array
     tmp(n+1) = value
     call move_alloc(from=tmp,to=array)
  end subroutine real_add  

  ! Helper function to fill an array (slow!)
  pure subroutine int_add(array,value)
     integer, allocatable, intent(inout) :: array(:)
     integer, intent(in) :: value
     integer, allocatable :: tmp(:)
     integer :: n
     n = merge(size(array),0,allocated(array))
     allocate(tmp(n+1))
     if (n>0) tmp(1:n) = array
     tmp(n+1) = value
     call move_alloc(from=tmp,to=array)
  end subroutine int_add  

end module simple_cli


program test_cli
   use simple_cli
   implicit none
   
   type(cli_options) :: cli

   ! Parse command line arguments
   call cli%parse()
   
   ! Pass to function
   call my_function(cli)
   
   
   contains   
   
   subroutine my_function(options)
      type(cli_options), intent(in) :: options
      
      print *, 'my_function received ',options%nA(),' "A" options: ',options%a(1:options%nA())
      print *, 'my_function received ',options%nA(),' "B" options: ',options%b(1:options%nb())
          
   end subroutine my_function    

end program test_cli
```

Examples of what the program returns:

```
$ a.exe 1 2.5 3.7 2 45 -125
 my_function received            4  "A" options:            1           2          45        -125
 my_function received            4  "B" options:    2.50000000       3.70000005

---

$ a.exe dont know
  catastrophic CLI error: cannot interpret command <dont>.
```

Comment: Command line interfaces are seldom used to parse _numbers_, and in the question, only two are used. But in some other comments, it's been pointed out that more input numbers may be needed (fields? tables?), in which case, using a CLI wouldn't be my topmost option